# Which style rules are used for the caret in a twitter-bootstrap select?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I have a weird case where the caret for the twitter bootstrap select is not appearing after some customisation. I am therefore looking to restore the style for the select. These are the current styles:

```
#sidebar2 select {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
  outline: 0;
  display:block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075) !important;
  border-radius: 2px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 32px !important;
  font-weight: 500;
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  text-transform: none;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use **-webkit-appearance: none !important**, it will make the caret disappear, you can try on mozzila and see the caret still there

Comment: thank you, you have no clue how much time I spent looking for this.